# laravel 5 service provider not working my web server

Tags: php, laravel-5

Laravel 5 service provider cannot working in web server but its working fine in my localhost details explain bellow

**App->Privider->MymoduleServiceProvider.php**

```
namespace App\Providers;
use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;
use App;
class MyModuleServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    public function boot()
    {
        //
    }
    public function register()
    {
         App::bind('mymodule', function()
        {
            return new \App\Module\MyModule;
        });
    }
}
```

I have make one folder named Module in this folder have two file

**App->Module**

**1. MyModule.php**

```
namespace App\module;
use Session;
class MyModule {

public function Vegitable($data){
          $veg = \App\models\veg::select('id')
                  ->where('vegs', $data)
                  ->get()->count();
          echo $veg;
      }
}
```

**2. MyModuleFacade.php**

```
namespace App\Module;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Facade;
class MyModuleFacade extends Facade{
    protected static function getFacadeAccessor() { return 'mymodule'; }
}
```

and i added in **config->app.php**

```
'providers' => [
     App\Providers\MymoduleServiceProvider::class
]
 'aliases' => [
    'MyModule'=> App\module\MyModuleFacade::class,
]
```

and calling in view like `{{MyModule::Vegitable($veg->proid)}}`

its working fine in my localhost(xampp) but not working my web server geting error message given bellow

```
ErrorException in AliasLoader.php line 66:
Class 'App\module\MyModuleFacade' not found (View: /home/pric/public_html/veg/demo/vegster/resources/views/veglist.blade.php)
```

Comment: i fixed this problem  in App->Module module folder starting capital "M" but in config->app.php aliases showing small "m"
you just add this
'aliases' => [
    'MyModule'=> App\Module\MyModuleFacade::class,
]

instead of

'aliases' => [
    'MyModule'=> App\module\MyModuleFacade::class,
]

Answer (score 0):

i fixed this problem  in App->Module module folder starting capital "M" but in config->app.php aliases showing small "m"

you just add this

```
'aliases' => [
    'MyModule'=> App\Module\MyModuleFacade::class,
]
```

**instead of**

```
'aliases' => [
    'MyModule'=> App\module\MyModuleFacade::class,
]
```